# Programmatically Update Image Labels

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to update my product images' labels.  I want them to be the same as the name of the product.

What I've tried

```
$mediaModel = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_backend_media");
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $mediaModel->updateImage(
        $product->getId(),
        $image->getFile(),
        array("label" => $title)
    );
}
```

But then I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 401

I've also tried

```
$mediaModel = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$images = $mediaModel->items($product->getId());
foreach ($images as $image) {    
    $mediaModel->update(
        $product->getId(),
        $image['file'],
        array("label" => $title)
    );
}
```

Which runs fine, but the values aren't updated in the admin.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Steve, what do you have in the method on the file Media.php on line 401?

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','xxxxxxxxx');

$mediaModel = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$images = $mediaModel->items($product->getId());
foreach ($images as $image) {
 $mediaModel->update(
     $product->getId(),
     $image['file'],
     array("label" => 'Image label here')
  );
 }
 $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'media_gallery');
```

This code is works for me. Clear cache before refresh backend

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$product->getImageLabel();
```